# show a trigonometric function is decreasing with constraints

Tags: calculus

The question reads:

You may use the fact that $\sin(t) \leq t$ for all $t \geq 0$
without proof whenever needed for this problem.

Show that if $a$ is a positive constant, then $x\cot(ax)$ is a decreasing function of x.

What I have so far:

Let  $f(x) = x\cot(ax)$, then $f'(x)= \cot(ax) - ax\csc^2(ax)$
or to put it in different terms, $\frac{1}{\tan(ax)} - \frac{ax}{\sin^2(ax)}$ .

At this point I am not sure what to do. Do I set the derivative equal to 0 and try to find critical points or do I show that the $\frac{ax}{\sin^2(ax)}$ will always be greater than the $\frac{1}{\tan(ax)}$ term and thus the derivative will always be negative?

Comment: But $x\cot(ax)$ is not really decreasing. We need additional conditions.

Comment: What about the case where $x \geq 0$ ?

Comment: Not enough.  For note that $\cot(ax)$ is negative for some $x$, and then later it is positive   for a while, then later  negative for a while, and so  on forever.

Comment: Interesting, this is the exact copy of an old exam question I was looking at, so I am not sure what to add besides that.

Comment: Maybe it is decreasing over any interval on which it is defined. I have not checked.

Comment: Oscillating between positive and negative values does not imply the function is not increasing if the function has singularities (which cot(ax), and hence x*cot(ax) does).

Comment: @patrickh The statement is only true if $f$ is restricted to $[0,\pi/a)$ or one of the  $(k\pi/a, (k+1)\pi/a), k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given are $a > 0$ and 
$$
\sin(t) \le t \quad (t \ge 0) \quad (*)
$$ 
The function is
$$
f(x) = x \cot(ax)
$$

The function $f$ is not defined for $x = k \pi/a, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
For $x = 0$ it can be extended to be continous there:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x \cos(ax)}{\sin(ax)} \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(ax) - ax\sin(ax)}{a\cos(ax)} \\
&= \frac{1}{a}
\end{align}

A graph of $f$ for $a = 1$:

[image: x cot x]
([Larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4HtF.png))

We have the derivative
$$
f'(x) = \cot(ax) - \frac{ax}{\sin(ax)^2}
$$

For $x \in (0, \pi/a)$ we have:
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \frac{1}{\sin(ax)^2} \left( \sin(ax) \cos(a x) - ax \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sin(ax)^2} \left( \frac{1}{2}\sin(2ax) - ax \right) \\
&\le \frac{1}{\sin(ax)^2} \left( \frac{1}{2}2ax - ax \right) \\
&\le 0
\end{align}
where we used the inequality $(*)$ and $a > 0$ such that $2ax \ge 0$.

For $x = 0$ we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x) 
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(2ax) - 2ax}{2 \sin(ax)^2} \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2a\cos(2ax) - 2a}{4a \sin(ax)\cos(ax)} \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2a\cos(2ax) - 2a}{2a \sin(2ax)} \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-4a^2\sin(2ax)}{4a^2 \cos(2ax)} \\
&= 0
\end{align}
where the L'Hôpital theorem was used twice.

A graph of $f'$ for $a = 1$:

[image: derivative]
([Larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGoEh.png))

As André pointed out in the comments, $f$ is decreasing on $[0,\pi/a)$ and intervals $(k\pi/a, (k+1) \pi/a), k \in \mathbb{N}$ but not on $\mathbb{R}^+ = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \ge 0 \} \setminus \{ k \pi/a \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Ok, I like this one better than mine...

Comment: Thanks. I have to think if one actually needs $f'(0) \le 0$ or if $f'(x) \le 0$ on $(0, \infty)$ is already good enough.

Comment: Note that it has not been shown that our function is decreasing, for indeed it is not. What is true is that in any **interval** in which the function is defined, it is decreasing. But there are singularities, and we can easily find $s\lt t$ such that $f(s)\lt 0$ and $f(t)\gt 0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You are right. I added a reference to your note and two graphs.

Answer (score 2):

With a little manipulation, you can show

\begin{equation}
\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{-1}{\sin^2(ax)}\left[ ax - \cos(ax)  \sin(ax) \right].
\end{equation}

Now $\forall x \ge 0$,
\begin{equation}
ax \ge ax|\cos(ax)|
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
ax - \cos(ax) \sin(ax) \ge ax|\cos(ax)| - \cos(ax)\sin(ax) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\ge ax|\cos(ax)| - |\cos(ax)|\sin(ax)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= |\cos(ax)|(ax - \sin(ax)) \ge 0.
\end{equation}
Furthermore, equality only holds when $x = 0$, so
\begin{equation}
\frac{df}{dx} < 0\, \forall x > 0.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x \geq 0$. The result is reversed otherwise.

We will need the following trigonometric identities:
\begin{align}
\tan(x)   &= \frac{\sin(2x)}{1+\cos(2x)} \tag1\\[2ex]
\sin^2(x) &= \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2} \tag2\\[2ex]
\cos^2(x) &= 1-\sin(x) \tag3
\end{align}

First notice that, using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain

$$ f'(x) = \frac{1}{\tan(ax)} - \frac{ax}{\sin^2(ax)} = \frac{1+\cos(2ax)}{\sin(2ax)} - \frac{2ax}{1 - \cos(2ax)}$$

Hence, we want to show that
\begin{align}
\frac{1+\cos(2ax)}{\sin(2ax)} &\leq \frac{2ax}{1 - \cos(2ax)} \\[2ex]
1 - \cos^2(2ax) &\leq 2ax \sin(2ax) \\[2ex]
\sin^2(2ax) &\leq 2ax \sin(2ax) \\[2ex]
\sin(2ax) &\leq 2ax  \\[2ex]
\end{align}

where $(3)$ was needed to obtain the third line. The result, then, follows by your initial observation that $\sin(x)\leq x$ for all $x \geq 0$ and the fact that $a>0$.